# Why does char.GetUnicodeCategory() report wrong categories?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

The character `0x1C90` represents the `GEORGIAN MTAVRULI CAPITAL LETTER AN` and is according to the official [Unicode documentation](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1C90.pdf) part of the general category `Lu` ("Letter, uppercase").

This is the entry from the official [Unicode 11.0 database](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt):

```
1C90;GEORGIAN MTAVRULI CAPITAL LETTER AN;Lu;0;L;;;;;N;;;;10D0;
```

However, the following .NET code:

```
char.GetUnicodeCategory('\x1C90')
```

returns `UnicodeCategory.OtherNotAssigned` for some reason.

What is the problem here? Do I have to install some specific .NET language pack so that the Unicode category is reported correctly? Is this a bug in the .NET Framework? I've tested it with up-to-date versions of the .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Note: `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory('\x1C90')` also reports the wrong category.

Comment: Hm, this is really weird. For anyone who's interested, I filed a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2013

Comment: According to this https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-11.0/ it's a new character in Unicode 11. In the remarks on MSDN, it says it is using version 5.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Oh, unfortunately, this information is not part of the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.getunicodecategory page. Thanks! This must be it!